# Continuous Conditional Probability Function Integration Region

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

SETUP: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2$ where $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1-x$.

I need to compute $P(Y\in (0, 3/4) | X=1/2)$.

I started this by first computing the marginal probability distribution of X by integrating $f_{X,Y}$ from $0$ to $1-x$ with respect to $y$. I got the result that

$f_{X}(x)=2(1-x)$

I then proceeded to compute the conditional distribution as the ratio of the joint and marginal distribution to get

$f_{Y|X} (y|x) = 1/(1-x)$.

Now I thought that the probability distribution of $Y|X$ is $U(x,1)$ i.e. uniform because of the formula I computed. Then

$f_{Y|X} (y|x=1/2) = 2$ and $Y|X$ is distributed $U(1/2,1)$.

I then thought that:

$P(Y\in (0, 3/4) | X=1/2)$ = $\displaystyle\int_{1/2}^{3/4} f_{Y|X} (y|x=1/2)dy  = \displaystyle\int_{1/2}^{3/4} 2 dy = 1/2$

The reason I used the bounds $1/2$ and $3/4$ is because the range on the uniform distribution starts on $1/2$.

Then I thought that perhaps this is wrong because from the setup of the problem $0<y<1-x$ which implies that if $x=1/2$ then $0<y<1/2$. This gives:

$P(Y\in (0, 3/4) | X=1/2)$ = $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1/2} f_{Y|X} (y|x=1/2)dy  = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1/2} 2 dy = 1$.

So now I am very confused about this issue and not quite sure that which approach (if any) is correct and why. Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: Of course the second approach is correct. It is really weird that after you calculating the conditional pdf without consider the support, you suddenly jump to the conclusion "because of the formula I computed". You always need to consider the support, as given by the joint pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SETUP: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2$ where $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1-x$.

Also written as:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)= 2\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1) ,y\in(0;1-x)}$$

At this point it should be readily apparent that when $X=1/2$ then the conditional support of $Y$ is $(0;1/2)$ so, whatever the density function may be, $\mathsf P\big(Y\in(0;3/4)\mid X=1/2\big)=1$.   No integration is actually required to obtain the answer.

However, to make a short story long:

> I started this by first computing the marginal probability distribution of X by integrating $f_{X,Y}$ from $0$ to $1-x$ with respect to $y$. I got the result that
>
> $f_{X}(x)=2(1-x)$

More correctly $f_X(x)=2(1-x)\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;1)}$ since it is zero outside the indicated support.

> I then proceeded to compute the conditional distribution as the ratio of the joint and marginal distribution to get
>
> $f_{Y|X} (y|x) = 1/(1-x)$.

Likewise: $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = (1-x)^{-1}\cdot\mathbf 1_{y\in (0;1-x), x\in(0;1)}$

> Now I thought that the probability distribution of $Y|X$ is $U(x,1)$ i.e. uniform because of the formula I computed.

Why would you think that?   Answer: Because you neglected to include the support in the function and lost track of where the function was zero valued and where not.

Noticing what the support is makes it clear that: $Y\mid X ~\sim~ \mathcal U(0;1-X)$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\in (0;3/4)\mid X=1/2) ~=~& \int_\Bbb R \left.(1-x)^{-1}\cdot\mathbf 1_{y\in (0;1-x), x\in(0;1)}\right\rvert_{x=1/2}\cdot\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;3/4)}\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_\Bbb R (\tfrac 12)^{-1}\cdot\mathbf 1_{y\in (0;1/2)\wedge y\in(0;3/4)}\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]~=~& \int_0^{1/2} 2\operatorname dy 
\\[1ex]~=~& 1
\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

**tl;dr** As BGM commented: "You always need to consider the support, as given by the joint pdf."   It *is* an imperative.

Comment: Thank You! This really helped me understand the stuff better.